# Shortest code to post a string to WebServer

Tags: code-golf, internet

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), this code posts `String to post` to `http://www.example.com/target`:

```
curl -d "String to post" "http://www.example.com/target"
```

**NOTE:** You should use **`http://www.example.com/target`** as the URL to `POST` to, without any change.

I think all other languages that I have knowledge in need a lot more code than this. I'm not blaming other languages. Let's see the interesting answers that reduce the effort.

Your task is to write the shortest code possible to send a **`POST`** request to a sample server, **`http://www.example.com/target`**, and the request data should be the string **`String to post`**.

Comment: It's not clear that the title and the body are asking for the same thing, let alone what you consider to be sufficient and necessary to qualify as a solution.

Comment: Dont you understand the question? this is the best i can explain. the title and body are clear for me

Comment: @Peter Taylor I have edited the question to try to make it more clear.

Comment: Another one of the same size: `POST http://www.example.com/target<<<'String to send'`. (`POST` is either a stand-alone script or symlink to `lwp-request`, a command line tool delivered with the [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP.pm) `perl` module.)

Comment: @manatwork why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @ace, I felt it's not valuable enough for an answer.

Comment: Is it sufficient that the request be permitted by the HTTP spec (and if so, which?), or is there a set of additional minimal headers to make it useful to the server?

Comment: I've reduced my answer by 3 bytes. Can you check it?

Comment: Yeah, updated... :)

Comment: I've reduced my answer by 9 characters!

Comment: @toothbrush Yeah updaetd that :)

Comment: Some of the answers are posting to `example.com`, and some to `www.example.com`. You may wish to clarify that requirement, one way or the other.

Comment: @ViswanathL Yes, I suggest you clarify.

Comment: Yeah i updated the url, Please change and update th answers accordingly

Comment: @ViswanathL OK. I've updated my solution, too. Do we really need the `http:` part, too?

Comment: @toothbrush. The `http:` part is the protocol. I'd presume that if your language infers the protocol, that's fine. But there is a real difference between `example.com` and `www.example.com`: they're two different names.

Answer (score 16):

## Bash: 90 characters

No external tools, just pure `bash`.

```bash
echo 'POST /target HTTP/1.0
Content-length:14

String to post'>/dev/tcp/www.example.com/80
```

Comment: That's Bash running on Linux.  I have a Bash commandline for my windows box but do not have /dev

Comment: Not sure whether it depends on /dev/, but /dev/tcp/ doesn't exist anywhere – it is just Bash's own syntax for opening a TCP connection. Personally I would expect it to work regardless the presence of /dev/. It certainly works in Cygwin, but I have a feeling that you use MinGW. Could you please @JerryJeremiah post us some details about this? Like Bash's version, the package from which it comes, what actually happens when you run my posted code. (By the way, should not happen anything _visible_ – Bash just connects, transfers, disconnects, exits with 0.)

Comment: I'm astonished to announce this works - even without a /dev/ directory!  I saw the /dev/ and jumped to a stupid conclusion.  I am running the bash version 3.1.17 from the bmatzelle/gow github repo.

Comment: For enybody else that never knew you could do that, look here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bashs-built-devtcp-file-tcpip

Answer (score 9):

## Rebol (51 chars)

```
write http://www.example.com/target"String to post"
```

Above works in Rebol 3.  Below is a Rebol 2 version (63 chars):

```
read/custom http://www.example.com/target[post"String to post"]
```

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript, 84

```
with(XMLHttpRequest())open('POST','//www.example.com/target'),send('String to post')
```

Try in the console of any page served over plain HTTP.

Comment: I think you can replace `http://www.example.com/target` with `://.example.com/target`

Comment: @ClydeLobo. Can you get rid of the `www`? I don't see how that's legitimate.

Comment: @TRiG OK. It's now fully compliant with the question.

Answer (score 5):

## Powershell v3 - 58

```
iwr http://www.example.com/target -b "String to post"-me 3
```

Answer (score 3):

### Lua (texlua), 73 bytes

```lua
require("socket.http").request("www.example.com/target","String to post")
```

Comment: The question said to `POST` to `http://www.example.com/target`.

Comment: @toothbrush: Thanks, I missed `www.`. I have updated the answer and also changed `.org` to `.com`. `http://` can be omitted, because it is the default.

Comment: Great! I know that you can omit the `http://` part - I wasn't saying to include it.

Answer (score 3):

## Smalltalk (Smalltalk/X), <strike>64</strike> 71

```
HTTPInterface post:'http://www.example.com/target'with:'String to post'
```

Comment: this contains 71 characters

Comment: sorry - you're right - I tested (and counted) another string to post. Embarrased!

Answer (score 3):

#### newLISP - 58 characters

```
(post-url "http://www.example.com/target""String to post")
```

Answer (score 3):

### PHP - 100 bytes

```php
<?fwrite(fsockopen('www.example.com',80),'POST /target HTTP/1.0
Content-length:14

String to post');
```

I apologize for any similarities to [manatwork's bash solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21765), but I believe that this is the shortest way to do it.

Comment: There is a solution I wasn't expecting. Well done!

Comment: You need to use `www.example.com`, not `example.com`.

Comment: @toothbrush they do resolve to the same IP. But I agree that  for fairness, everyone should be using exactly the same URL (and, that the question was modified after this was posted to make that explicit).

Comment: @primo Yes, that's true. However, the question **did** originally say that the code should `POST` to `http://www.example.com/target`.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash - 63 chars

```
wget --post-data="String to post" http://www.example.com/target
```

Answer (score 3):

## Tcl - 85 chars

```
package require http
http::geturl "//www.example.com/target" -query "String to post"
```

Answer (score 2):

## VBScript: 114 characters

```
dim x:set x=createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
x.open"post","http://example.com/target"
x.send"String to post"
```

Comment: Slightly smaller: `With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP"):.Open"POST","http://example.com/target":.Send"String to post":End With`

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: The question now states that you need to `POST` to `http://www.example.com/target`. Note the **`www.`** part.

Answer (score 2):

### Game Maker Language (GMStudio), 66

```
http_post_string("http://www.example.com/target","String to post")
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2: 80 chars

Just using the standard library:

```
import urllib2 as u
u.urlopen("http://www.example.com/target","String to post")
```

For an extra char, you can make the import less unusual.

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com/target","String to post")
```

Comment: If you want to gain another char: **__import__('urllib2').urlopen("http://www.example.com/target","String to post")**

Comment: Sneaky. I like it

Answer (score 2):

## jQuery, 58

`$.post("http://www.example.com/target", "String to post");`

Comment: jQuery isn't a programming language...

Answer (score 2):

## , 47 chars / 51 bytes (noncompetitive)

```
ɟŏ`//www.example.com/target⍪String to post
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=false&input=&code=%C9%9F%C5%8F%60%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Ftarget%E2%8D%AAString%20to%20post)</kbd>

Uses jQuery's `post` function.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 198 bytes

This is shamefully large...:

```php
<?fopen('http://www.example.com/target','rb',0,stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('method'=>'POST','header'=>'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','content'=>'String to post'))));
```

At least I answered!

Comment: The second one complains that the `HTTP wrapper does not support writable connections.` If it were to do anything, it would attempt to overwrite the contents of the http request with the given string.

Comment: That's why I said that I'm not sure if it works. But I will remove the second answer.

Comment: The answer was removed, but still can be seen on the edit option.

Comment: But surely the Content-Type is `text/plain`, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default mime-type to **send** data to a server, `text/plain` is the default mime-type to **receive** any non-binary text without a declared mime-type.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 69 bytes

```
lwp-request -m POST -b http://www.example.com/target "String to post"
```

You can read about the `lwp-request` command here: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_POST.htm

I think that the answer given by @manatwork is a much more neat and compatible version.

Answer (score 1):

### Actionscript 3, 201

```
var aRV:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
aRV.STRING = "my string";
var aR:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.example.com/target");
aR.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
aR.data = aRV;
var aL = new URLLoader();
aL.load(aR);
```

no error handling

Answer (score 1):

## Batch/Powershell - 118 Chars

If you need to post from a Windows batch file or avoid changing ExecutionPolicy:

```
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).UploadString('http://www.example.com/target', 'p1=String%20to%20Post')"
```