# Write a program that downloads itself

Tags: code-golf, quine, internet, self-referential

Write a program that connects to this site, downloads the very answer in which it is posted, extracts its own source code and prints it out. The output must be identical to the source code. Shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Rules:

- No URL shorteners allowed.
- The answer must have a regular format - a heading with the language name and size, optional description, code block, optional description and explanation. No unnatural delimiters allowed.
- The output must originate from the actual code block posted on the site.
- The functionality must not depend on the position in the answer list; it should work even if there are multiple pages and the answer it not on the first one.
- **New:** special note for answers that are supposed to be run in a browser: it  is ok to require running them on the codegolf domain (to obey the same-origin policy) but the domain and path should be included in the solution in order to make it fair.

Comment: Catch-22: How am I supposed to test my submission?

Comment: I forsee people posting answers and deleting them, so they can test their code.

Comment: @m.buettner answers can be tested on other answers (to other questions) first, then posted, then edited to change the URL :)

Comment: I think the participants should agree on a code of conduct that no two answers will be in the same language with the same character count (i.e. be a gentleman and use an additional character if there's a tie), such that everyone can save characters but not having to scrape for author or ID of the post (so posts can be identified by the headline directly). ;)

Comment: @m.buettner I'm not sure that would save characters... basically I can allow this technique, but I won't require such conduct

Comment: I bet the next question will be a program that program itself.

Comment: How does this challenge handle comments designed to interfere with an answer?

Comment: @hexafraction if comments are able to interfere with an answer, then the answer is not very good...

Comment: Given enough answers one submission might end up on page 2, 3, ... Must the solutions account for this?

Comment: @Sylwester yes I already mentioned that in the question

Comment: A question stuck in my head: How to write a tweet that links to itself without using any URL shorteners, but by estimating the tweet id your tweet?

Comment: @Sylwester that shouldn't be a problem - if you use the direct link to the answer (instead of the question), the correct page should be open already.

Comment: Concerning your new rule for JavaScript because it is powerful on this question is just like create a rule *"Only language used in production accepted"* because GolfScript is not fair for the majority of code-golf questions. Anyway, this is just my opinion...

Comment: @Michael The rule is just about the circumstances of running the code. It's like saying that a program that prints "/0/1/2/3/.../20" must not depend on being executed in a folder with that exact path. And if only production languages were accepted, somebody **WILL** use GolfScript in production :)

Comment: is jQuery allowed? (and more broadly, is this commonly allowed/disallowed in this site?)

Comment: @Martijn I see no reason to exclude it, as long as it follows the rules

Comment: I proposed the opposite of this a bit ago: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/proposed-question-sandbox-mark-xii-retired/1528#1528 it never came to fruition.

Comment: @m.buettner I love the way your catch-22 comment has exactly 22 upvotes :D
Here: http://i.imgur.com/twJzcfa.png

Comment: @SHiNKiROU That does not apply here, as you can post the answer and then edit it to include the url of the answer

Answer (score 36):

## Bash + coreutils + Lynx browser, 61 bytes

Thanks to @FDinoff for the tips:

```
lynx -dump codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28164/body|grep 2
```

Comment: And what happens if I type that magic word grep is looking for?

Comment: lynx lynx lynx lynx. This comment will be grepped out (and the heading as well)

Comment: @hexafraction Awww. You had to go and ruin it!

Comment: I would assume that no answer above you can use a "keyword" so you could select only the first result.

Comment: Or he could just be more specific with something like grep `lynx -d` to match where the -dump flag is. Oh wait... Thats broken now too

Comment: `codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28154/write-a-program-that-downloads-itself` can be replaced with `codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28154`.

Comment: This url should work. `codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28164/body` And it ignores comments. I also think its within the rules that you can use it...

Comment: `lynx -dump codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28164/body|tail -1` is 62 characters. (I think it should work if you edit your answer)

Comment: @FDinoff Thats great!  Thanks!

Comment: 2 2 2 2 2 2 does it still work?

Comment: @haneefmubarak Yep, still works :)  Comments are not included in the changed URL format, as recommended by FDinoff.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma awww... damn.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Okay, you're right. I thought it was a typo since the Q no. is 28154.

Comment: `curl` doesn't work?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere I'm not aware that curl has an equivalent to lynx's `-dump` option, that just outputs the page content, and not the html tags

Answer (score 24):

## Ruby, <s>155</s> <s>186</s> <s>195</s> <s>148</s> <s>138</s> <s>110</s> 97 characters

```ruby
require'open-uri';puts open('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28159/body').read[/req.+;/];
```

I had to make it one line, because otherwise it would output newlines as `\n` instead of actual newlines.

- <s>+31 characters because I didn't notice some characters were being escaped.</s>
- <s>+9 characters to get rid of the annoying backslash.</s>
- Thanks to Nathan Osman for saving 2 chars, and Ventero for saving 55 (!!!) by removing the need for most of the fixes listed above.

---

### The explanation

Let's beautify this a bit first. However, I'm going to have to use a somewhat... interesting notation in this code. I can't use semicolons at all in this post, for reasons explained later, so I will use `{SEMI}` in place of semicolons instead.

```
require 'open-uri'
resp = open('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28159/body').read
puts resp.match(/req.+{SEMI}/){SEMI}
```

Alright, now let's walk through this. The first two lines are fairly self-explanatory -- they fetch the HTML text of this answer.

Now, the last line is the interesting one here. You see that seemingly useless semicolon at the end of the code? It's absolutely required, and here's why.

First, `resp.match` extracts the code to be printed. The regexp it uses for this is the trick: `/req.+{SEMI}/`. It grabs the start of the code, `REQuire'net/http'`, by searching for `req` (`re` would grab my `REputation`). Then, it finds the end of the code by searching for a semicolon! Since `+` is greedy by default, it will keep going until it finds the semicolon that signifies the end of the code. See why I can't use semicolons anymore?

<s>After that, I don't have to unescape anything thanks to Ventero's fix of not using `\` at all anymore. All I have to do is fix `{AMPERSAND}` changing into `{AMPERSAND}amp{SEMI}`, which can be achieved simply by removing the `amp{SEMI}` part.</s> No need for this anymore because of new URL. After that, the original code has been retrieved! *(Note: I can't use the ampersand either, because that gets HTML-encoded which causes a semicolon to be created.)*

Comment: Some characters are getting escaped..

Comment: @aditsu Gah; didn't notice that. Fixed.

Comment: You're gonna hate this.. a backslash is getting duplicated. There's also a newline difference, but that's a minor thing.

Comment: @aditsu Argh! :P Fixed also. The newline thing is because of `puts`; it could be fixed with `print` but meh. Just pretend there's a trailing newline in the code, even though SE won't be able to show it.

Comment: You can shave off two bytes by using `withbody` in the filter instead of `!9WA((ItYa`.

Comment: `.body[/e>.+?</][2..-5]` should save quite a few characters.

Comment: And with something like `.body[/req.+-3./]`, you can save even more, especially because then you can drop the `CGI.unescapeHTML` call (plus the require), and instead use `.sub("amp;","")`. Also, using `require"open-uri"` and `open("http://api.stack....").read` saves even more - though this requires Ruby >= 2, I think. To fix the newline, use `$><<` instead of `puts` (which saves another character).

Comment: (With the `.sub` call, you'll have to change the RegExp to `/req.+""./`, if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: @Ventero Wow! Thanks. I have to use `net/http` because otherwise un-gzipping the API's output costs too much. Can't use `$><<` because then I'd have to unescape `<` and `>`, which costs more than it saves. I also altered your regex a bit.

Comment: @Doorknob: When you use Ruby 2, you get uncompressed output from `open-uri`. But yeah, missed the part about unescaping `<>`. And I like the seemingly useless semicolon! :)

Comment: @Ventero Hm. I'll look into that in a sec; I'm writing up an explanation right now. Thanks; I'm particularly proud of that semicolon trick because I find it extremely clever for some reason :P

Comment: With the new URL, you don't need the `.sub` anymore. And maybe you could use a similar trick with the semicolon at the beginning of your code (e.g. by prepending your code with another semicolon or an exclamation mark or something), which could save another character.

Comment: For the link,  `http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28159` would give the same result as yours and would save some chars.

Comment: I believe that the `require'open-uri';` can be passed as a command line argument as `-ropen-uri`, which would save more bytes

Answer (score 21):

### PowerShell - <strike>69</strike> 62

```
(irm codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28236/body).div.pre.code
```

Comment: DOM in a shell. Nice!

Comment: Doesn't irm require Azure Rights Management? Without that module, I think you could do it with  Invoke-WebRequest.

Comment: @ScottLeadley `irm` is the alias for `Invoke-RestMethod` and was introduced with PowerShell v3 core. http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell3-alias.htm

Comment: Holy crap. A PowerShell code golf answer with a length in the same order of magnitude as the leading answers. +1

Comment: @AdamMaras Ha, I know what you mean! It does happen occasionally though. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26811/4565 and http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21982/4565 weren't too far from the lead.

Comment: @bfred.it: strictly speaking, this isn't DOM, which refers to a specific API rather than any HTML/XML APIs.

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript - <strike>123</strike> <strike>122</strike> <strike>101</strike> <strike>95</strike> <strike>92</strike> <strike>91</strike> <strike>87</strike> <strike>86</strike> 114

```
with(new XMLHttpRequest)send(open(0,/\codegolf.stackexchange.com\posts\28175\body/,0)),alert(/w.*/.exec(response))
```

Runs in the console of your web browser on this page. Tested on the latest Chrome <strike>and Firefox</strike>.

*edit: +28 bytes to add the full domain.*

*Firefox doesn't like my Regex URL trick anymore with this update :(*

Here's the rule-breaking 86 byte solution:

```
with(new XMLHttpRequest)send(open(0,/posts\28175\body/,0)),alert(/w.*/.exec(response))
```

Comment: That made me awe. Multiple times.

Comment: @bfred.it I just cut a byte using an interesting regex. I hope it makes you awe one more time.

Comment: If printing to the console is an acceptable method of output, you can shorten by 7 chars by removing the alert.

Comment: Also , according to the new rule you gotta add `codegolf.stackexchange.com/` to the url.

Comment: @TejasKale From what I've seen people frown upon solutions that don't actually alert/document.write/console.log the answer.

Answer (score 10):

## Ruby + wget + <strike>gunzip</strike>, <strike>159</strike> <strike>86</strike> <strike>82</strike> 71

Using tip of @FDinoff to use `http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28173/body`.

```
puts `wget -qO- codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28173/body`[/pu.*\]/]
```

Tested. Thanks to @ace and @Bob for command line optimization.

Comment: You can combine the flags in `wget`, as in `wget -qO- url`. Also, in bash you do not need the double quotes for the url, so this may also work for you.

Comment: You can leave out the `http://`.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam - 53

```
"codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28184/body"g54/1=);
```

I'm making this community wiki since I'm answering my own question and don't really want to compete :p
Credits to FDinoff for the URL choice.

Comment: Woot, +1 for smiley face in code

Comment: @Cruncher `);` doesn't look too smiley to me...

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript, 228

```js
r=new XMLHttpRequest()
c='code'
r.open('GET','//'+c+'golf.stackexchange.com/posts/28157/body')
r.onreadystatechange=function(){this.readyState==4&&alert((a=r.responseText).substr(i=a.indexOf(c)+5,a.indexOf('/'+c)-i-1))}
r.send()
```

Runs on this page.

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: @aditsu It is supposed to be run on the JavaScript console of a browser. But I am still testing (and fixing) it, please wait

Comment: @aditsu It should work now. Open your browser console (press F12) and paste this code there.

Comment: you sir, need a `if(this.readyState == this.DONE)` inside the function.

Comment: @Fabricio You're right! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can save 10 chars, if you ommit the parens from the XMLHttpRequest and use `with` instead of assigning the XHR to `r`. `with(new XMLHttpRequest){open('GET','/posts/28157/body');onreadystatechange=function(){if(readyState==4)alert((a=responseText).substr(i=a.indexOf(c='code')+5,a.indexOf('/'+c)-i-1))};send()}`

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 I know I can, but I'd rather not, otherwise people may think I am copying the other JS answer. (And in fact I got an un-upvote after copying the URL...)

Comment: @ace I see :) I didn't saw the other js answer until now. Then take this upvote from me

Comment: Nice answer. How do you get the URL of your post?

Comment: @bacchusbeale By clicking the "share" button below the answer, you can see the post number 28157. As for the format of the URL (`/posts/[number]/body`), I copied it from other's answer... Originally I used the StackExchange API.

Answer (score 5):

### Java now 634, 852, was 1004

Code has been updated; thanks for suggestions.
Golfed: now replaces &gt with >

```java
//bacchus
package golf;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class G{
public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
Scanner z;
URL u;
int x=0;
String s;
u=new URL("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28154/write-a-program-that-downloads-itself");
z=new Scanner(u.openConnection().getInputStream());
z.useDelimiter("\\s*//bacchus\\s*");
while(z.hasNext())
{
s=z.next();
s=s.replace("&gt;", ">");
if(x>0)System.out.println("//bacchus\n"+s);
x++;
if(x>2)break;
}
System.out.println("//bacchus\n");
}
}
//bacchus
```

Submitting for testing, I will edit and try golfing it shortly.
Needed to change x>1 to x>2 because test string is also in my code.
Note: Code golf replaces > symbol to &gt.

```java
//bacchus
package golf;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Golf {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL u;
        URLConnection c;
        InputStream i;
        InputStreamReader r;
        BufferedReader b;
        String s;
        int x=0;
        try {
            u=new URL("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28154/write-a-program-that-downloads-itself");
            c=u.openConnection();
            i=c.getInputStream();
            r=new InputStreamReader(i);
            b=new BufferedReader(r);
            while((s=b.readLine())!=null)
            {
                if(s.contains("//bacchus")) x++;
                if(x>0)System.out.println(s);
                if(x>2) break;
            }
            i.close();
            b.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

        }
    }

}
//bacchus
```

Comment: How do you handle comments containing `//bacchus`?

Comment: You could inline a lot of stuff, try-with-resources, and use `*` imports to save a lot of code.

Comment: @SimonKuang - I'd also just leave the streams open rather than closing stuff.  Also, `throws Exception` rather than trying to handle anything.  Also, I think using a Scanner rather than a BufferedReader would be simpler, especially as you could set the delimiter to `//bacchus`, which would make things somewhat easier...

Answer (score 5):

## Python, <strike>175</strike> 167 bytes

This uses two external libraries; I didn't read that it was unauthorized.

```py
import bs4,requests
print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28154').text).select('#answer-28171')[0].select('pre > code')[0].string)
```

Longer, but nicer looking code:

```py
import bs4, requests
request = requests.get('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28154')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text)
answer = soup.select('#answer-28171')[0]
code = answer.select('pre > code')[1].string
print(code)
```

Comment: The `questions` in the url can be replaced with `q`: `http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28154`

Comment: The space in `bs4, requests` (line 1) can be removed to reduce 1 byte.

Answer (score 5):

## Rebmu, 91 characters

<strike>Due to the Catch-22 I have to post to get this answer's URL.  :-/  Okay, got it.</strike>

```
paTSrd http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28154[th<a name="28154">th<code>cpCto</code>]prC
```

Rebmu is a dialect of Rebol, and [you can read all 'bout it](https://github.com/hostilefork/rebmu).  The equivalent Rebol here would be:

```
parse to-string read http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28154 [
    thru <a name="28154">
    thru <code>
    copy c to </code>
]
print c
```

Rebol's PARSE is a sort of highly-literate answer to RegEx.  It starts a parser position of the input *(which can be any series, including structural blocks...binary data...or string types)*.  The rules are a language for how the parse position moves.

Tags and URLs are really just strings under the hood in the language.  But they are "flavored", and as Rebol is dynamically typed you can check that type.  READ for instance knows that if you give it a URL-flavored string, then it should dispatch to a scheme handler to do the reading.  (In this case, the one registered for HTTP).  You get back UTF-8 bytes by default, so we use to-string to decode that and get a series of codepoints in a normal Unicode string.

In the case of the parse dialect, encountering a tag type is just matched as if it were a string that looked like the tag.  THRU is an instruction meaning "skip until the ensuing rule is matched, and then place the match position at the end of what you just matched."  (TO is the analogue that matches, but leaves the parse position before the element).

So we zip along past the `<a name="28154">`.  Then we zip past the next occurrence of `<code>`, with our parse position now located right after the `>`.  PARSE's COPY command then lets us copy data up to another rule, in this case that rule is `[TO </code>]`... so we get into the variable C everything up until right before that `<`.

[Cool](http://blog.hostilefork.com/why-rebol-red-parse-cool/), huh?  :-)

Technically I could shave more off it, for instance by seeking `TO "</"` and that saves three characters--there's no need to match the whole `</code>` end tag when just `</` would do.  Similar arguments could me made for the start tag.  But Rebmu is about *literate* golfing...even if you might think it looks odd at first!

**UPDATE**: the `/body` trick is out of the bag, but I'm similarly going to leave it as-is...because I think it is more educational this way.

Answer (score 5):

### w3m 45 characters

```
w3m codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28336|grep ☻
```

Comment: ☺. Does it still work? **Edit:** Looks like it does.

Comment: @ace I get your comment when I run it

Comment: Fixed :) Anyone else? 

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <strike>563</strike> 613 bytes

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.List
import Network.HTTP
m%f=join(fmap f m)
q s=(simpleHTTP(getRequest"http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28154/write-a-program-that-downloads-itself?answertab=oldest#tab-top"))%getResponseBody%(putStrLn.head.filter((==)(s++show s)).map(take 613).tails)
main=q"import Control.Monad\nimport Data.List\nimport Network.HTTP\nm%f=join(fmap f m)\nq s=(simpleHTTP(getRequest\"http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28154/write-a-program-that-downloads-itself?answertab=oldest#tab-top\"))%getResponseBody%(putStrLn.head.filter((==)(s++show s)).map(take 613).tails)\nmain=q"
```

Tested. Has page support via "oldest posts" feature. Uses quine-line structure to find what to print.
The `import Control.Monad` is only because `>>=` generates `&gt;` in HTML.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript +jQuery, <strike>87</strike>, 67

I'm not sure wether I'm allowed to use jQuery, but:

```
$('body').load('//codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28268/body pre')
```

---

#### Javascript + jQuery, if excecuted in this page: <strike>27</strike>, 25

For fun, if it would be excecuted here:

```
$('[id$=268] pre').html()
```

<strike>`$('[id$=28268] pre').html()`</strike>

Comment: This outputs more than the source code.

Comment: 67: `$('body').load('//codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28268/body pre')`

Comment: You are correct, I wrongly asumed the whole reply instead of the code

Answer (score 3):

## Dart, 164

I thought I'd try this in Dart, is pretty fun to use imo.

This can be run in the console in DartEditor, but does require the http package added in pubspec.yaml

```
import"package:http/http.dart"as h;h.read("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28215/body").then((s){print(new RegExp(r"im.+(?:})").firstMatch(s).group(0));});}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
import "package:http/http.dart" as h;

void main()
{
  h.read("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28215/body").then((s)
  {
    print(new RegExp(r"im.+(?:})").firstMatch(s).group(0));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### R 114 characters

```
library(XML);cat(xpathSApply(xmlParse("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28216/body"),'//code',xmlValue)[1])
```

No real magic here: it takes the value of the field between the html tags `<code></code>`. Uses library `XML` (as one can see in the code quite obviously). Outputs the result as stdout.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 108 bytes

```apl
6 3⌷⎕XML{(⎕SE.SALT.New'HttpCommand'('GET'⍵)).Run.Data}'https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/211205/body'
```

[Don't Try it online, try it locally](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///30zB@FHP9kd9UyN8fao1gHSwq16wo0@Inl9qubpHSUmBc35ubmJeirqGurtriPqj3q2amnpBpXl6LoklibXqGUAVxVb6@sn5Kanp@TlpesUlicnZqRXJGYl56al6yfm5@gX5xSXF@kaGhkYGpvpJ@SmV6v//AwA)

<s>Correct link coming soon.</s>

### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## bash + awk, 71 bytes

```
curl -sL codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28154 |awk -F\> '/\#/ {print $3}'
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - it outputs a lot of other stuff along with this answer.

Comment: @Riking true, it seems to be position-dependent (breaking the last rule)

Comment: You can leave out the `http://`.

Comment: @user155406: note that each answer has a URL - this one is  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28179/14710

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>237</s> <s>215</s> <s>146</s> 132

```rb
require'mechanize'
a=Mechanize.new
puts a.get('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28159').search('.lang-rb code:nth-child(1)').text
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can remove a few spaces here and there to save a few bytes.

Comment: @richard who cares I'm not going to win anyway.

Comment: Do it for the lols, not for winning.

Comment: @RichardA done, and I also removed few chars from the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>300</s> 294

```
import java.net.*;import java.util.*;public class G{public static void main (String [] a) throws Exception{Scanner s=new Scanner(new URL("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28189/body").openConnection().getInputStream()).useDelimiter("./?[c]ode\\W");s.next();System.out.print(s.next());}}
```

An improved version of bacchusbeale's answer which:

- doesn't close resources unnecessarily
- doesn't declare unnecessary variables
- uses a `Scanner` to avoid having to loop over the input
- uses a regexp that doesn't match itself to avoid having to skip over a middle occurrence of the start/end marker.

Updated:

- Use a direct URL to the post, so we don't need a unique comment to identify the start/end of the code; now uses `<code>[...]</code>` as the delimiters to search for (actually using the regular expression "./?[c]ode\W", so as to avoid having to decode `&lt;` and `&gt;` -- the "\W" is necessary rather than the shorter "." to avoid it matching part of the URL to the post, unfortunately, which costs 2 characters, and the square brackets around c prevent the regex matching itself).

Comment: You have a bunch of unnecessary spaces. Also your class doesn't need to be public.

Comment: openConnection().getInputStream() can also be shortened to openStream()

Answer (score 1):

## w3m 55 bytes

```
w3m codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28242/body|grep x
```

Based on @DigitalTrauma

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 164

Works by extracting the text between the code tags. It is quite long but it will always function correctly unless the html page is edited directly or a new code block is added before the one below (having a block of code after should have no effect on the output of the program).

```
import urllib2
print urllib2.urlopen("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28617/body").read().split(chr(60)+"code"+chr(62))[1].split(chr(60)+"/code"+chr(62))[0]
```

Comment: Very late but I appreciate the smart use of `chr()` to avoid the code containing any characters that need escaping.

Answer (score 1):

## Processing, 90

```
print(loadStrings("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28657/body")[2].substring(11));
```

**Edit:** Finally got it!

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 138

```
a=window.open("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28160/body");setTimeout('alert(a.document.body.innerHTML.match(/a=.*9\\)/)[0])',99)
```

This works assuming that the page loads in under 99 ms. It also has to be run via a console opened on a codegolf.SE page, because of the same origin policy.

Comment: Just a note: you don't need the slug in the URL, and questions can be replaced by q.

Comment: Note that you could do `http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28160` instead of `http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28160/12551`

Comment: Chrome doesn't like this: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined"

Comment: @Spedwards you should disable the popup blocker.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 5.10, <strike>155</strike> <strike>127</strike> <strike>122</strike> 117 bytes

```
use XML::LibXML;say XML::LibXML->new->parse_file('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28330/body')->find('//pre')
```

Using `XML::LibXML`.

Answer (score 0):

### Shell and xmllint, 82 bytes

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//pre)' http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/28333/body
```